# Java app Heroku Application Error - SEVERE: A child container failed during start

Tags: java, tomcat, heroku, ssl-certificate, heroku-ssl

After adding a SSL certificate to my app in Heroku, it worked for a few hours, until the dynos were restarted.

Basically it was an http app, and i needed to change it to https, so all i did was adding the SSL certificate, following the heroku documentation, and it worked for a few hours.

Now I get the Application Error.

Looking at the logs it shows:

```
Aug 24 09:45:33 my-app app/postgres.85:  [ORANGE] [3858-1] LOG:  restartpoint starting: time 
Aug 24 09:45:33 my-app app/postgres.85:  [ORANGE] [3859-1] LOG:  restartpoint complete: wrote 0 buffers (0.0%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 10 recycled; write=0.001 s, sync=0.000 s, total=0.018 s; sync files=0, longest=0.000 s, average=0.000 s; distance=163840 kB, estimate=163844 kB 
Aug 24 09:45:33 my-app app/postgres.85:  [ORANGE] [3860-1] LOG:  recovery restart point at 32/B000060 
Aug 24 09:45:33 my-app app/postgres.85:  [ORANGE] [3860-2] DETAIL:  last completed transaction was at log time 2016-08-25 15:42:11.925539+00 
Aug 24 09:45:34 my-app app/heroku-postgres:  source=HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ORANGE sample#current_transaction=1935 sample#db_size=7536812.0bytes sample#tables=0 sample#active-connections=2 sample#waiting-connections=0 sample#index-cache-hit-rate=0 sample#table-cache-hit-rate=0 sample#load-avg-1m=0 sample#load-avg-5m=0 sample#load-avg-15m=0 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=4045204.0kB sample#memory-<br />Aug 24 09:45:34 my-app app/web.2:  Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them. 
Aug 24 09:45:34 my-app app/web.2:  Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx2g -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
Aug 24 09:45:35 my-app app/web.2:  Expanding oauthxxxx-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war into /app/target/tomcat.27162/webapps/expanded 
Aug 24 09:45:35 my-app app/web.2:  Adding Context  for /app/target/tomcat.27162/webapps/expanded 
Aug 24 09:45:35 my-app app/web.2:  INFO: No global web.xml found 
Aug 24 09:45:35 my-app app/web.2:  Aug 24, 2016 4:45:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment 
Aug 24 09:45:35 my-app app/web.2:  Aug 24, 2016 4:45:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init 
Aug 24 09:45:35 my-app app/web.2:  INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-27162"] 
Aug 24 09:45:35 my-app app/web.2:  INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read 
Aug 24 09:45:35 my-app app/web.2:  Aug 24, 2016 4:45:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal 
Aug 24 09:45:35 my-app app/web.2:  INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.30 
Aug 24 09:45:35 my-app app/web.2:  Aug 24, 2016 4:45:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin 
Aug 24 09:45:36 my-app app/web.2:  Aug 24, 2016 4:45:35 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector 
Aug 24 09:45:36 my-app app/web.2:  INFO: Starting service Tomcat 
Aug 24 09:45:36 my-app app/web.2:  Aug 24, 2016 4:45:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal 
Aug 24 09:45:36 my-app app/web.2:  WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'antiJARLocking' to 'true' did not find a matching property. 
Aug 24 09:45:37 my-app heroku/web.2:  State changed from starting to up 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:  Aug 24, 2016 4:45:38 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:  SEVERE: A child container failed during start 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:  java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]] 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871) 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:  Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]] 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:   ... 6 more 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:   at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.cleanupInitMaps(InitFacesContext.java:281) 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:   at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.<init>(InitFacesContext.java:106) 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:   at com.sun.faces.config.FacesInitializer.onStartup(FacesInitializer.java:114) 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5244) 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:   ... 6 more 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:  Aug 24, 2016 4:45:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:   at webapp.runner.launch.Main.main(Main.java:261) 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:  Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]] 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:  INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. 
Aug 24 09:45:38 my-app app/web.2:  Aug 24, 2016 4:45:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
```

Not sure if adding the certificate caused the issue, but that was the only change i made, other than some change in the postgre database.

I didn't change the code, so i'm not sure if you guys can tell me something about this.

Thanks,

Comment: If you're going to post a wall of code, can you at least put it in a code block?

Comment: Can you describe what you did when "adding a SSL certificate"? The Tomcat output doesn't contain much to go on.

Comment: Basically it was an http app, and i needed to change it to https, so all i did was adding the SSL certificate, following the heroku documentation, and it worked for a few hours.

Comment: Not sure if adding the certificate caused the issue, but that was the only change i made, other than some change in the postgre database.
I didn't change the code, so i'm not sure if you guys can tell me something about this.